# how to solve user objects problem when VLC activex web plugin v2 media player playing in c#?

Tags: c#, media-player, vlc, libvlc

I have one problem. I m using axVLCplugin for media player . When my form is opening long time user objects limit over 10000 . AxVLCPlugin creating this problem. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: axVLCplugin is unsupported now, use libvlcsharp

Comment: how can I use libvlcsharp it has media player component? Also Will it solve user objects increasing problem ?

Comment: try the samples, and see the platforms supported (all except web)

Comment: hi @mfkl libvlcsharp very complex according vlc active plugin. I cannot find any auotloop autoplay also playlist options. Do you have any idea ?